# Nontrivial solution of a fourth-order DE with variable coefficients$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(f(x)\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}\right)-ag(x)y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

How to find the general closed-form solution of the following eigenvalue problem?
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(f(x)\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}\right)-ag(x)y(x)=0
\\ \text{where} \ 0< f(x),g(x)\leq 1,\ 0\leq x \leq 1,f(x) \text{ and } g(x) \text{ are continuous in }[0,1],
\\ a>0 \text{ is the eigenvalue, and} \ y(x) \text{ is the mode shape to be solved in terms of } f(x) \text{ and } g(x). 
\\ \text{Boundary conditions: } y(0)=0,{y}'(0)=0, y(1)=0,{y}'(1)=0
\end{equation}
It is a beam vibration problem. Tried many methods, failed by far.
Are there any references to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE. Maybe, can you show your attempts?

Comment: I want to solve for $y(x)$ and $a$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. This is a classical problem for vibrations of non-uniform beam. $y(x)$ is the mode shape, and the frequency can be represented by $a$.

Comment: I doubt that it has a closed form solution for general $f(x), g(x)$.